# What is the right way to return a completed future?

Tags: java

So I have a function that is returning a CompletableFuture, and I am wondering if there is the difference between the two use cases below:

Case 1:

```
CompletableFuture<String> future = new CompletableFuture<String>();            
ForkJoinPool.commonPool().execute(() -> {
    future.complete(value);
});
return future;
```

Case 2:

```
return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(value);
```

Comment: If this example is real, then why are you using futures at all? If it's after a long-running execution, then **case 2** is the correct way (as you already have the result)

Comment: maybe I should give a better example, but I am wondering when is a good time to use the static method of `CompletableFuture.completedFuture()`

Comment: Use `CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Object)` whenever you already have the result but need to wrap it in a `CompletableFuture`. Besides, _case 1_ doesn't really make sense in the context of your example; you might as well simply do `ComletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> value))`.